# Can I get a opengl compatibility context with mesa in linux?

Tags: c, linux, opengl

I'm getting started with OpenGL and decided to go with OpenGL 2.1. The reason I want to do this is, because it's easier and I want my programs to be compatible with old hardware. However I don't know if I can get a compatibility profile in linux.

Can I get OpenGL 2.1 program working in a linux machine with mesa (let me be more specific there, a mesa's version that implements the OpenGL 3.x+)?
If not, using OpenGL 2.1 makes my programs being less compatible with new hardware (in linux)? 
Don't know what to do here. Any help is apreciated

I am a Linux developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL 2.1 has no concept of compatibility profiles; that only appears in OpenGL 3.x+, where using the compatibility profile adds back the features that were removed.

If you request an OpenGL 2.1 context and you get it, you're all set. And yes, Mesa supports OpenGL 2.1.

Using an old version of GL could, in theory, make your program incompatible with a driver that only supports OpenGL 3.1+ with only the core profile. In practice though, virtually every desktop GPU driver still supports old OpenGL.

Comment: what i meant is: if use opengl 2.1, will my program run on a linux pc with a mesa's version that implements opengl 3.3? Because I heard that mesa's implementation of opengl 3.3 doesn't have the compatibility profile, so i don't know if my opengl 2.1 program would work.

Comment: Mesa may not support the compatibility profile for 3.3, but that doesn't mean it doesn't support OpenGL 1 and 2. You just won't be able to access features added in 3.3 from a pre-3 context. Also, why not just try it yourself? It's not that hard to check if you use a library like GLFW.